# Calculating "TotalshiftTiming - (Break01 + Lunch +Break02)

Tags: mysql

I have a table that displays shift start time, break 01 start time, break 01 end time, lunch start time, lunch end time, break 02 start time, break 02 end time, 
shift end time.
Here I wanted to calculate everything in minutes.

```
Time = TotalShiftTime - ((break01Start - break01endtime) + (lunchstart - lunchend) + (break02start - break02end))
```

I want to calculate this in minutes on daily basis. I want to calculate this with respect to start date and end date which i wanted to give as input. 
It has to be like

```
[(endDate - startDate) * Time]
```

If my `endDate` is `07/03/2018` and `startDate` is `04/03/2018` I want it to be `[3 * Time]`.

PS: I don't have a column for `startDate` and `endDate`. I want to get cumulative minutes when I select system date.

How can I achieve this?

```
Shiftstart | Brk01start | Brk01end | LunchStart | LunchEnd | Brk02Start | Brk02end | Shiftend
8:00:00    | 11:15:00   | 11:45:00 | 13:00:00   | 13:30:00 | 15:15:00   | 15:30:00 | 17:00:00
```

Comment: So, what have you done so far or where's your code? Or what problem do you have?

Comment: HI, I am a beginner and I don't know how to make this condition work.Should I create a stored procedure for this?

Comment: You probably should start from tutorials and simpler examples then. It's probably going to be pretty much the same SQL, regardless if you have a procedure or not.